# Why this regexp via preg_replace function of PHP not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to remove all strings that are like this: **"REP_HSC_QUALIFIED"** using the following expression, but somehow it is not working. Can somebody help in pointing out my mistake (I rarely use regular expressions, so I do not have good understanding of it).

```
preg_replace('#REP[a-zA-Z0-9_]+#', '-', $data);
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the regex. Show the actual code you have. Are you sure `$data` contains that text? Is `$data` a string? Are you assigning the result to a variable (in the question you aren't doing it)?

Comment: @Juhana, preg_replace() function returns data or perform action on variable itself.

Comment: Um, no. `preg_replace()` leaves the original value untouched.

Comment: @Juhana, Thanx for the hint, I was not assigning the data to a variable. It is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you propably want to do

```
$data = preg_replace('#REP[a-zA-Z0-9_]+#', '-', $data);
```